# Is it possible to reference the chained object in a method call chain?

Tags: scala, chaining, method-chaining

I have a builder call chain in which one of the calls must append to the default value, e.g.

```
var x = new X()
  .setA(1)
  .setB(2)
x = x.setList(x.getList :+ "itemtoappend")
```

Is there any way to inline the setList call? 
(X is a 3rd party library)

I'm hoping there is be a keyword, say "chain", used like this:

```
val x = new X()
  .setA(1)
  .setB(2)
  .setList(chain.getList :+ "itemtoappend")
```

Assuming I don't have the ability to write an appendToList method on X, and don't want to write and implicitly convert to/from a class MyX that has appendToList.

Comment: Real world use cases I am hoping to simplify include adding a few new words to Spark ML StopWordsRemover, and adding new columns to a Spark DataFrame as functions of existing columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to access the object twice at the same time you're building it.

```
class X {
  def setA(a: Int): X = this
  def setB(b: Int): X = this
  def setList(ss: Seq[String]): X = this
  def getList = Seq("head")
}

val x: X = Option( new X().setA(1).setB(2)
                 ).map(z => z.setList(z.getList :+ "itemtoappend")).get
```

Comment: Great, this does inline everything so that x can be immutable. The intent of this code wasn't immediately obvious to me. Is it a common pattern?

Comment: Glad you like it. (Maybe you can mark it as the accepted answer?) No, I don't think this is a common pattern. I realized that the parameter passed to an anonymous function is an intermediate representation of the object being built. I used `Option().get` to create/discard a wrapper that provides a `map()` method.

Comment: I've accepted, thank you. I was waiting to see if there was any other suggestion, but none forthcoming. I'm using this with slight tweak of using Some instead of Option:
`Some(new X().setA(1).setB(2)).map(z => z.setList(z.getList :+ "itemtoappend")).get`

Comment: Indeed.  `Option`/`Some`, pretty much the same thing. I like to use `Option` because `Option(null)` is `None` whereas `Some(null)` is `Some(null)`. Probably not applicable in this case but something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard approach is write a method that does both setting and getting, being passed a function. You'd call it as

```
val x = new X()
  .setA(1)
  .setB(2)
  .list(_ :+ "itemtoappend")
```

Comment: Thanks. That's certainly better than my appendToList idea, more generalised, but i think still requires me to invent MyX and implicitly convert?

Comment: Ah, right, I though you were asking about how to implement an `X`, not that you want to write the chain with a given `X`. Yeah, either an implicit conversion to `MyX`, writing it out with `var x`, or filing a feature request with `X`'s author are your options.